# How can I submit a form into a node and save it in the database?

Tags: nodes

I installed drupal 8 in local and i have created a content type named 'Formulaire' and also i've created a FormulaireForm and i want to submit this form into that node .how can i do this ?
and i also want to storage this values into the database.

Comment: add a field in your and store node id of node in this field

Answer (score 0):

Your FormulaireForm is made by webform? Under this case, you can use rules to create node automatically.
[image]